# replacing specified characters with others in of a given string in python

Tags: python

I am practicing python so there's a problem:

given strings;

```
 string1 = "abc" ,string2 = "xyz"
```

I need

```
result: xyc abc
```

its with a space.

Comment: How exactly do you want to swap? Are there any rules for it? What have you tried?

Comment: Q. Write a Python program to get a single string from two given strings, separated by a space and swap the first two characters of each string.  exaple: "abc" "xyz". Expected result:   "xyc abz"

Comment: so that would give "xbc ayz" given   string1 = "abc" ,string2 = "xyz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string1 = "abc" 
string2 = "xyz"
string2 = string2[0:-1]+string1[-1]
res = f'{string2} {string1}'
print(res)
```

Output

```
xyc abc
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the specific problem must be :

`print(string2 + " " + string1)`

String concatenation means add strings together.

Use the + character to add a variable to another variable

Comment: Wrong. Please read the question again. Note that the question is currently closed because it's not clear. You might better wait until the question is clear, otherwise your answer doesn't make sense.